# Odd character out given two strings

Tags: java, string

Beginner here -

I need to find the odd character out in a set of two strings. Everything compiles but when it goes to print out the odd character, it prints out the characters of the longer string..Does anyone know how i can fix it?

thanks

```
public class odd
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str1;
    String str2;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 2 words:");
    str1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    str2 = keyboard.nextLine();


   int n1 = str1.length();
   int n2 = str2.length();

   int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

  if (Math.abs(n1-n2)==1)
  {
    if (n1 > n2)
    {
      x1 = n1;
      x2 = n2;
    }

   if(n1 < n2)
   {
    x1 = n2;
    x2 = n1;

    String temp = str1;

    str1 = str2;
    str2 = str1;
  }
    }
  else
  {
    System.out.print("Invalid input.");
  }



 for (int i=0; i < x1; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < x2; j++)
   {
     if(str1[i]==str2[j])
     {
       System.out.println("Extra letter is: " + str1[i]);
       break;
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(str1[i]==str2[j])
 {
   System.out.println("Extra letter is: " + str1[i]);
   break;
 }
```

You're checking if the character matches, and then printing if it does, when your stated intention is the opposite: to check if they differ, and then print if that is the case. Change your **==** to **!=** and you should get the desired result.

For the sake of clarity, **==** is the equal-to operator, and **!=** is the not-equal operator.

Comment: I did that and it still printing out more than one character. Is there something wrong with the string arrays?

Comment: Your break statement only breaks from the inner loop. If you want to exit both loops after printing, you'll need a label. Better practice would be to put the inner loop in a separate function, but in your example:
for (int i=0; i < x1; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < x2; j++)
   {
     if(str1[i]==str2[j])
     {
       System.out.println("Extra letter is: " + str1[i]);
       break;
     }
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Sorry:
` outerloop:
for (int i=0; i < x1; i++)
 {
   for (int j = 0; j < x2; j++)
   {
     if(str1[i]==str2[j])
     {
       System.out.println("Extra letter is: " + str1[i]);
       break outerloop;
     }
   }
  }
 }
`

Comment: ok awesome that worked! Now its printing out: Enter 2 words:
chase
arches
Extra letter is: a ------- the extra letter should be r

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget the rep! ;)

Comment: Can you help me with the problem of the extra letter being wrong! I won't gorget about the rep

Answer (score 0):

For you program to work your first string minus second string must be equal to 1:
Math.abs(n1-n2)==1
Fix this piece of code, Hint: is it needed ?

Comment: Yes because the two strings should only be one character off because I am supposed to find the odd character out. Should i change str1[i] to str1.charAt(i) ?

Comment: Yes, you are looking for a charAt.

Answer (score 0):

@jjuutz Use below method to get the difference between two strings.

```
public static String difference(String str1, String str2) {
if (str1 == null) {
    return str2;
}
if (str2 == null) {
    return str1;
}
int at = indexOfDifference(str1, str2);
if (at == -1) {
    return EMPTY;
}
return str2.substring(at);
}


public static int indexOfDifference(String str1, String str2) {
if (str1 == str2) {
    return -1;
}
if (str1 == null || str2 == null) {
    return 0;
}
int i;
for (i = 0; i < str1.length() && i < str2.length(); ++i) {
    if (str1.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) {
        break;
    }
}
if (i < str2.length() || i < str1.length()) {
    return i;
}
return -1;
}
```